# Permission to write my alert in android's calendar

Tags: java, android, calendar, manifest

How can i do to write my alert into android's calendar? what permission i must add in manifest.xml?

I've no idea and whitout that i can't complete my app.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The permissions that you will need to deal with the Calendar are,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```

Please see the [Android Calendar Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#reminders), the details are in there.